# Compare two columns ftp_start_time and ftp_stop_time and return the count of columns based on conditions

Tags: sql-server

[Compare two columns ftp_start_time and ftp_stop_time and return the count of columns based on conditions :3 columns are 1.Tried(count(ftp_start_time))  2.Success(count of ftp_start_time and ftp_stop_time when not null)  3. Failed(count of ftp_stop_time must be null).. please help

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gor6f.png)

```
SELECT 
    a.Branch_code,
    b.DevCount AS total,
    COUNT(a.ftp_start_time) AS tried
FROM 
    ftplogview AS a
LEFT JOIN 
    palmtecsetup AS b ON a.Branch_code = b.Branch_code
WHERE 
    ftp_start_date = '2016-03-31'
GROUP BY 
    a.Branch_code, b.DevCount
ORDER BY 
    Branch_code
```

This is the query I used so far ...can anyone help me out?

Comment: Your images did not link to this question.

Comment: @RizwanaNazeer I can see ftp_stop_date and ftp_stop_time as NULL. Are those the columns that you are referring ?

Comment: I have mistyped Questions..its actually ftp_start_time and ftp_stop_time comparison

Comment: what is condition of comparison

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this one will help you, use the sub select query like below -

```
    SELECT 
        q.Branch_code,
        q.DevCount AS total,
        COUNT(q.ftp_start_time) AS tried,
        SUM(Success) AS SuccessCount,
        SUM(Failed) AS FailedCount,
        SUM(NOTTRIED) AS NOTTRIEDCount
    FROM
    (
        SELECT
            a.Branch_code,
            b.DevCount AS total,
            a.ftp_start_time AS tried,
            CASE WHEN a.ftp_start_time IS NOT NULL AND a.ftp_stop_time IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Success,
            CASE WHEN a.ftp_start_time IS NOT NULL AND a.ftp_stop_time IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Failed,
            CASE WHEN a.ftp_start_time IS NULL AND a.ftp_stop_time IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS NOTTRIED
        FROM 
            ftplogview AS a
        LEFT JOIN 
            palmtecsetup AS b ON a.Branch_code = b.Branch_code
        WHERE 
            ftp_start_date = '2016-03-31'    

    ) Q
    GROUP BY 
        Q.Branch_code, Q.Total
    ORDER BY 
        Q.Branch_code
```

Comment: Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
The multi-part identifier "a.Branch_code" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
The multi-part identifier "b.DevCount" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 5
The multi-part identifier "a.ftp_start_time" could not be bound.
I get this error after trying the above code....!!

Comment: very helpful...  Thanks a lot!!! That helped me out.. thanks for being patient to help me ...

Answer (score 0):

I would use Common table expression

```
with cte(Branch_code, DevCount, total,ftp_start_time,ftp_stop_date,ftp_stop_time ) 
as (
SELECT 
    a.Branch_code,
    b.DevCount,
    a.ftp_start_time,
    a.ftp_stop_date,
    a.ftp_stop_time
FROM 
    ftplogview AS a
LEFT JOIN 
    palmtecsetup AS b ON a.Branch_code = b.Branch_code
GROUP BY 
    a.Branch_code, b.DevCount
 )
 SELECT  Branch_code,
    DevCount AS total,
    COUNT(ftp_start_time) AS tried,
    SUM(
    case  
       when ftp_start_time  is not null and  ftp_stop_time is not null then 1
       else 0 end
       ) as success,
    SUM(
       case  
          when ftp_stop_time is null then 1
          else 0 end
          ) as failed
 FROM CTE
 WHERE ftp_start_time =  '2016-03-31'
```

Comment: Actually in the front end the user must select date based on which the data gets fetched...This code does not apply on that

Comment: So, please explain your problem better, otherwise it would be difficult to help you accordingly.

Comment: I have added one more image can u please check?

Comment: So, do  you want to look for all the rows with a certain ftp_start_date, and whose ftp_stop_date and ftp_stop_time are not null?

Comment: yeah u r right..actually I want 4 columns based on 4 different conditions applied on the ftp_start_time and ftp_stop_time...                                          The 4 columns are 1.Tried 2.Success 3.Failed 4.Not tried...                            Count(ftp_start_time) is tried and when both ftp_start_time and ftp_stop_time not null it is success...when ftp_stop_time alone is null its failure...can u understand my problem..I dont know how to create single query based  on these conditions

Comment: I want the count of not null columns...how to obtain that?

Comment: @RizwanaNazeer Update the question with all conditions. Refer this to ask question - http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Rizwana, do you understand that your question was not formulated correctly? Please, update the question once and for all, and do not keep asking things in comments.

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping me patiently...I finally got answer as expected..and sorry for the trouble